# Syntax Highlighting in VIM to match first/last letter of line

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to to setup syntax highlighting in VIM to match the whole line only if the first non-whitespace character is "-" or if the last non-whitespace character of the line is ":". A typical line has many tabs in front of text.

For instance I have lines like this (with tabs in front of the text):

> - Go Home today
>
> Eat vegetables:

I don't however want to match these (not end or beginning of line).

> Go - Home today
>
> Eat : vegetables

I have tried various iterations but can't get it right.
For instance the following only highlights dashes, including every dash in file. I want it to highlight the whole line if the last or beginning characters match.

```
syn region dash start=/\v-/ end=// oneline
highlight link dash String
```

I know I just need to get my start/end searches right, but am having no luck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
syn region dash start=/^\s*\zs-/ end=/$/ oneline
syn region dash start=/^/ end=/:\ze\s*$/ oneline
highlight link dash String
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Is there a way to create a region for text does does not start with "-" or end with ":"? Some combination of the above?

Comment: @che_kid Negations are always tricky.  Here's one that almost works: `syn region nondash start=/^\s*\zs[^-]/ end=/[^:]\ze\s*$/ oneline`